# Width allocation of HTML table columns depends on row count

Tags: html, css

I've found a very strange behavior of a HTML table, where the width allocation of the cells depends on the count of rows. If I have 2 rows the cells have all the same width but when I insert another row the first column expands a little and the second column is narrower than the others. 
I have uploaded an example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPPAL/). 
You can see this behavior when you delete the comment around the third row in the HTML.

Where does this behavior come from?

Comment: In what browser? Why do you expect browser to render same width cells without telling the desired proportions? Why do you think that would be expected behaviour? The cells are rendered by the engine and how it is done depends on the table specifications, if not, they are calculated based on multiple factors to make a best fit in relation to specifications (CSS) and its content as well your browser window. It also depends what HTML version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells will expand to the content unless they have a fixed width. In your example you have table inside tables. Tables tend to have default values such as padding and cell spacing.

To get around this you can use a reset style sheet and modify the CSS of the table and its cells to your choosing

You may need to also perform CSS declarations such as collapsing borders if you really want it to be pixel perfect.

Comment: +1 Fine details. will be helpful in understanding the background

Answer (score 2):

actually columns expands and oontract on the base of contents inside the header or cells

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/aPPAL/1/

see the results.